# Cannot get physics to work properly, everything goes mental

Tags: animation, physics

The pivot is set to rigid body passive. The see-saw is set to rigid body active.
The block is placed on the end of the see-saw and is set to rigid body active. I used the snapping to faces to place the block on the end so there are no gaps.

All transforms have been applied.

The moment I hit play the block flies up into air and shoots off screen!

All of my physics simulations seem to do this. Why on earth is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot see the settings of the seesaw in the screenshot, but I would guess you have *Collisions* > *Shape* at the default *Convex Hull*, like the cube. A convex hull is not taking any concave shapes, cavities, holes, indentations into account.

So I presume you have placed the cube inside the convex hull of the seesaw, and whenever you place an active rigid body object inside the boundaries of a collision shape, it gets immediately thrown out when the simulation starts.

[image: convex hull]

So what you have to do is set the shade to *Mesh* instead of *Convex Hull*, as you can see in the image below. This takes even complex meshes into account for simulation. The reason this is not default setting is simply, the more complex the collision shape, the more computational power is needed and the longer it takes to bake a simulation. So if a *Convex Hull* is sufficient, stick with it. For simple shapes likes cubes and spheres etc. you also have special collision settings: these primitive shapes get simulated even quicker and more accurate. For the cube you could use the shape *Box* for example.

[image: mesh]

Comment: Thank you. That made a radical change, but I'm still encountering problems. I set the see saw to mesh and pushed play. The cube still jumps up, but only slightly this time, before coming down and pushing the see-saw down. When I set the cube to the box setting the cube just passes directly through the see-saw. Changing the mass on either object has no effect. Any suggestions on what I need to change?

Comment: @smashingtuck Without your file or seeing your settings this is all blind guessing... when you've switched to _Mesh_, presumably the default _Collision Margin_ of 0.04 m is set. This means, since you made sure there are no gaps as I've read in your question, that the cube is still inside the collision shape by 4 centimeters. For the cube... I don't know idk, it should work. As I said hard to tell without the chance to investigate it. Does the cube have its origin point in the center of the geometry?